# Can't SSH into EC2 instance launched from an autoscale group

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

**TL;DR:** I am spawning an EC2 instance using an autoscale group, and I can *connect* to it. But I cannot successfully *log in* to that instance using the SSH key pair I specified in the autoscale group.

---

I have used Terraform to create an autoscale group to launch an EC2 instance. Here is the autoscale group:

```hcl
module "ssh_key_pair" {
  source  = "cloudposse/key-pair/aws"
  version = "0.18.3"

  name      = "myproj-ec2"

  ssh_public_key_path = "."
  generate_ssh_key    = true
}

module "autoscale_group" {
  source  = "cloudposse/ec2-autoscale-group/aws"
  version = "0.30.0"

  name      = "myproj"

  image_id                    = data.aws_ami.amazon_linux_2.id
  instance_type               = "t2.small"
  security_group_ids          = [module.sg.id]
  subnet_ids                  = module.subnets.public_subnet_ids
  health_check_type           = "EC2"
  min_size                    = 1
  desired_capacity            = 1
  max_size                    = 1
  wait_for_capacity_timeout   = "5m"
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  user_data_base64            = base64encode(templatefile("${path.module}/user_data.tpl", { cluster_name = aws_ecs_cluster.default.name }))

  key_name = module.ssh_key_pair.key_name

  # Auto-scaling policies and CloudWatch metric alarms
  autoscaling_policies_enabled           = true
  cpu_utilization_high_threshold_percent = "70"
  cpu_utilization_low_threshold_percent  = "20"
}
```

And the `user_data.tpl` file looks like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo ECS_CLUSTER=${cluster_name} >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config

# Set up crontab file
echo "MAILTO=webmaster@myproj.com" >> /var/spool/cron/ec2-user
echo " " >> /var/spool/cron/ec2-user
echo "# Clean docker files once a week" >> /var/spool/cron/ec2-user
echo "0 0 * * 0 /usr/bin/docker system prune -f" >> /var/spool/cron/ec2-user
echo " " >> /var/spool/cron/ec2-user

start ecs
```

The instance is spawned, and when I SSH into the spawned instance using the DNS name for the first time, *I can successfully connect.* (The SSH server returns a host key on first connect, the same one listed in the instance's console output. After approving it, the host key is added to `~/.ssh/known_hosts`.)

However, despite having created an `ssh_key_pair` and specifying the key pair's `key_name` when creating the autoscale group, I am not able to successfully *log in* to the spawned instance. (I've checked, and the key pair exists in the AWS console using the expected name.) When I use SSH on the command line, specifying the private key half of the key pair created, the handshake above succeeds, but then the connection ultimately fails with:

> debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
> ec2-user@myhost.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).

When I use the Connect button in the AWS Console and click the "SSH client" tab, it says:

> No associated key pair
>
> This instance is not associated with a key pair. Without a key pair, you can't connect to the instance through SSH.
>
> You can connect using EC2 Instance Connect with just a valid username. You can connect using Session Manager if you have been granted the necessary permissions.

I also can't use EC2 Instance Connect, which fails with:

> There was a problem connecting to your instance
>
> Log in failed. If this instance has just started up, wait a few minutes and try again. Otherwise, ensure the instance is running on an AMI that supports EC2 Instance Connect.

I'm using the `most_recent` AMI with regex `amzn2-ami-ecs-hvm.*x86_64-ebs`, which as I understand it comes pre-installed with EC2 Instance Connect.

Am I missing a step in the `user_data` template? I also read something somewhere about the instance's roles possibly affecting this, but I can't figure out how to configure that with an automatically generated instance like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you've posted now, and in your previous questions, is correct. There is no reason why you won't be able to ssh into the instance.
You must make sure that you are using `myproj-ec2` private ssh key in your ssh command, for example:

```
ssh -i ./myproj-ec2 ec2-user@<instance-public-ip-address>
```

Also `ec2-instance-connect` is not installed on ECS-optimized instances. You would have to manually install it if you want to use it.

p.s. I'm not checking your user_data or any iam roles, as they are not related to your ssh issues. If you have issues with those, new question should be asked.

Comment: Using the proposed ssh command I discovered that my key file had the wrong permissions (0644 not 0400). Somehow this error wasn't showing when using a Host in the ssh config file. I also installed EC2 Instance Connect via `yum` in the `user_data` template, not sure if that helped. Anyway, thank you!!